# Relation between $\sum_{}^{} a_{k} z^k$ ad $\sum_{}^{} a_{k} x^k$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a power series, where 
$$f(z)= \sum_{}^{}a_{k} z^k. $$
Does it true that if $f(z)$ converges for every $x\in \mathbb{R},$ then it converges for every  $z\in \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: What do you know about the radius of convergence of a power series?

Comment: it converges for $|z| <1$

Comment: That depends on the power series. Some converge for $\lvert z\rvert < \frac{1}{3}$, some for $\lvert z\rvert < 12$, yet others …. Abstractly, what does the radius of convergence of a power series tell you about the values of $z$ for which it converges?

Comment: [Entire functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).

Comment: Sorry .if it converges at $z_{0}$ then it converges for $|z| <|z_{0}|$ and diverges for $|z| >|z_{0}|$ So the answer is yes .

Answer (score 0):

Is it that The radius of convergence gives you were the series is absolutely convergent ?

The only cases i see is for z on the circle with the radius of convergence like $\sum \frac { (-1)^n}{n}z^{2n}$ the radius of convergence is 1. But the sum converges for z=+-1 whereas it diverges for i,-i.

Comment: The radius of convergence of this series is $\pi/2$, not $\infty$—even for real $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof In Complex analysis with applications by "S.PONNUSAMY".

Suppose that $\sum_{}^{}a_{k}z_{0}^k$ diverges for some complex value $z_{0}$for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\sum_{}^{}a_{k} R^{k}$ diverges for R >|$z_{0}$| Contradiction .

Answer (score 0):

The [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) $R$ of a series $\sum a_nz^n$ has the property that the series diverges whenever $|z|>R$ and converges whenever $|z|<R$.

Hence, if the series converges for all real $x$, the radius of convergence must be infinite, and so the series also converges for all complex $z$.